# RabbitMQ в кубере

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes

Как правильно развернуть RabbitMQ в k8s? Что  написать в YAML?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй начать использовать helm: https://helm.sh/

Это своеобразный пакетный менеджер для k8s. С ним установка rabbit (и любых других приложений) в k8s будет следующей:

Сначала нужно найти чарт (пакет), который ты хочешь использовать:

```
17:55:22 ⟩ macosx % helm search repo rabbit
NAME                                CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
stable/prometheus-rabbitmq-exporter 0.5.5           v0.29.0     Rabbitmq metrics exporter for prometheus
stable/rabbitmq                     6.17.2          3.8.2       Open source message broker software that implem...
stable/rabbitmq-ha                  1.38.2          3.8.0       Highly available RabbitMQ cluster, the open sou...
```

Потом просто установить найденный чарт:

```
17:56:08 ⟩ macosx % helm install rabbitmq stable/rabbitmq
NAME: rabbitmq
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Mar  5 17:56:21 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
** Please be patient while the chart is being deployed **

Credentials:

    Username      : user
    echo "Password      : $(kubectl get secret --namespace default rabbitmq -o jsonpath="{.data.rabbitmq-password}" | base64 --decode)"
    echo "ErLang Cookie : $(kubectl get secret --namespace default rabbitmq -o jsonpath="{.data.rabbitmq-erlang-cookie}" | base64 --decode)"

RabbitMQ can be accessed within the cluster on port  at rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local

To access for outside the cluster, perform the following steps:

To Access the RabbitMQ AMQP port:

    kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/rabbitmq 5672:5672
    echo "URL : amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/"

To Access the RabbitMQ Management interface:

    kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/rabbitmq 15672:15672
    echo "URL : http://127.0.0.1:15672/"
```